# How to add HTML data inside a XML tag - Oracle XML DB options?

Tags: xml, oracle

I am trying to fetch data from database in XML format using Oracle XML DB options.One of the column in DB contains data in HTML format. But the HTML data is loaded as below

```
<sampleData> &lt;HTML&gt;
      &lt;Title&gt;A sample page header&lt;/Title&gt;
        &gt;body background="white"&lt;
        ...</sampleData>
```

is there any way to fix this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`DBMS_XMLGEN.convert`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96616/arxml30.htm#1009220) function to convert the encoded HTML to regular HTML

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d5e55/7) is an example in a fiddle

Answer (score 2):

That data has been originally stored like that. It's a standard means of encoding XML [entities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references) within an XML text element (otherwise - how would you reliably parse `<` and `>` within an XML text element?)

You need to extract that text element and it'll reveal itself to be of the form:

```
<HTML><TITLE>...
```

etc. At that point I'd reach for an HTML parser if you need to do more with it.